# R: multivariate orthogonal regression without having to write the variable names explicitly

Tags: r, linear-regression, polynomials, orthogonal

I have a dataframe `train` (21 predictors, 1 response, 1012 observations), and I suspect that the response is a nonlinear function of the predictors. Thus, I would like to perform a multivariate polynomial regression of the response on all the predictors, and then try to understand which are the most important terms. To avoid the collinearity problems of standard multivariate polynomial regression, I'd like to use multivariate orthogonal polynomials with `polym()`. However, I have quite a lot of predictors, and their names do not follow a simple rule. For example, in `train` I have predictors named `X2`,`X3` and `X5`, but not `X1` and `X4`. The response is `X14`. Is there a way to write the formula in `lm` without having to explicitly write  the name of all predictors? Writing

```
OrthoModel=lm(X14~polym(.,2),data=train)
```

returns the error

```
Error in polym(., 2) : object '.' not found
```

EDIT: the model I wanted to fit contains about 3.5 billion terms, so it's useless. It's better to fit a term with only main effects, interactions and second degree terms -> 231 terms. I wrote the formula for a standard (non-orthogonal) second degree polynomial:

```
`as.formula(paste(" X14 ~ (", paste0(names(Xtrain), collapse="+"), ")^2", collapse=""))`
```

where `Xtrain` is obtained by `train` by deleting the response column `X14`. However, when I try to express the polynomial in an orthogonal basis, I get a parse text error:

```
    as.formula( 
         paste(" X14 ~ (", paste0(names(Xtrain), collapse="+"), ")^2", "+", 
               paste( "poly(", paste0(names(Xtrain), ", degree=2)", 
                      collapse="+"), 
               collapse="")
     )
     
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with that approach, one of which you already see but even if the dot could be expanded within `polym` you would still have faced an error when it came time for the `2` to be evaluated, because `degree` is a parameter after the "dots" in the `polym` argument list and it therefore must be supplied as a named parameter rather than just positionally offered.

An approach using `as.formula` succeeds (with the 'Orthodont' dataframe in pkg:nlme (although using 'Sex' as the dependent variable is statistically nonsense). I took out the "Subject" column from the data and also took out the "Sex" from the names passed to `paste`:

```
data(Orthodont, package="nlme")
lm(   as.formula( paste("Sex~polym(" ,
                        paste(names(Orthodont[-(3:4)]), collapse=","),",degree=2)")), 
      data=Orthodont[-3])

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste("Sex~polym(", paste(names(Orthodont[-(3:4)]), 
    collapse = ","), ",degree=2)")), data = Orthodont[-3])

Coefficients:
                        (Intercept)  polym(distance, age, degree = 2)1.0  
                             1.4433                              -2.5849  
polym(distance, age, degree = 2)2.0  polym(distance, age, degree = 2)0.1  
                             0.4651                               1.3353  
polym(distance, age, degree = 2)1.1  polym(distance, age, degree = 2)0.2  
                            -7.6514
```

Formula objects can be created from text input with `as.formula`. This is essentially an application of the last example in `?as.formula`.

Comment: Looks great! I'll test it tomorrow and accept the answer, if it works. Thank you! BTW, can you explain why `collapse=","` is needed as an argument for `paste`? Also,I've sometimes seen `paste0` used in the context of building a formula, as opposed to `paste`. Any reason why I should prefer a form or the other?

Comment: The comma(s) is/are used to separate the `names` given as the argument list of `polym`. It doesn't really matter whether `paste` or `paste0` are used in building formulas unless you are trying to make names that get pasted together with no spaces, say with a stem of "X" and a sequence of numbers. Then you might prefer to use `paste0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works, at least in theory: in practice I get an out of memory error "cannot allocate vector of size 26.0 Gb". That's reasonable - I was asking for an horrible model with roughly 3.5 billions coefficients!!!!! Nonononono. `polym` is definitely useless here. Must think of something else...

Comment: I started modifying an answer (by you, what a coincidence!) to an older question of mine and I think I may be on to something. I edited my question since it doesn't fit in the comments. Can you help me getting the last bits right?